# Handle Database Connection Errors in Spring Boot during startup and after startup

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have following configuration in application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/demodb
spring.datasource.username=postgres
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.session.store-type=jdbc
spring.session.jdbc.initialize-schema=always
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.lob.non_contextual_creation=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I want to handle database connection error gracefully and the application should not stop working due to failure of database connection.

I want the application to handle the error both during startup and after startup.

I'm getting following exception when my database is down:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:245) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49) ~[postgresql-42.2.2.jar:42.2.2]
    ...
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_172]
    ...
```

In @ControllerAdvise, I tried to handle error after startup, but the exception is not getting caught:

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class AppAdvise {

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(PSQLException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public AppResponse psqlExceptionHandler(PSQLException ex) {
        return helpers.getResponseErrorObject(ex.getMessage());
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @ExceptionHandler(JDBCConnectionException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
    public AppResponse psqlExceptionHandler(JDBCConnectionException ex) {
        return helpers.getResponseErrorObject(ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

How can I handle the connection errors both at startup and after startup?

Comment: Can you try to use @EnableAutoConfiguration along with at the rate EnableAspectJAutoProxy, in spring boot main class and check and let me know.

Comment: @Sambit added the 2 annotations to main class but same issue

Comment: Do you want this to be loaded during spring boot startup only ?

Comment: The application should handle error during startup and after startup

Comment: I don't think it is possible during start of db connection failure. It works if your resource layer throws some exception.